# Angular2 V3 router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to the new v3 router.  I was able to update my package json to point to the alpha and install it.  I am getting this error everywhere...

node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts(80,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

Is there something else I need to upgrade.  I remember reading something somewhere about update typings.  I tried npm install typings -g with no such luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the typings are included in TypeScript compiler configuration. You can include them in few ways:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [
    ...,
    "typings.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

or include `typings.d.ts` content in one of the first files compiler looks for (like, `main.js` or `bootstrap.js`):

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

This points to the `typings/` folder and a file that has all definitions you installed using `typings install whatever` command, for example this is the file [AngularCLI](http://cli.angular.io) generates:

```
// browser.d.ts
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/angular-protractor/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser/ambient/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts" />
```

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'

This error tells you that compiler cannot locate definitions for Promise, which are located in `es6-shim/index.d.ts`.